# Functional test: how to set JSON data in a POST method?

Tags: json, symfony1, functional-testing

I want to create a functional test for an action that receives a POST method with data in JSON format.

This is what I have:

```
  info('set car')->
  post('/user/'.$user->getId().'/set-car/'.$car->getId()'->

  with('request')->ifFormat('json')->begin()->
    isParameter('module', 'myModule')->
    isParameter('action', 'myAction')->
  end()->
```

But..where should I set the receiving json data?

sf 1.4

Regards

Javi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you checked out the [page](http://www.symfony-project.org/jobeet/1_4/Doctrine/en/09) from Jobeet tutorial?

The first example is

```
$browser = new sfBrowser();

$browser->
  get('/')->
  click('Design')->
  get('/category/programming?page=2')->
  get('/category/programming', array('page' => 2))->
  post('search', array('keywords' => 'php'))
;
```

It may be that I didn't understand you question at all.
Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Thanks, but in the action I'm retrieving the JSON date through $request->getContent(). So, if I write the JSON data as in the post() function you pasted, I'm getting 'NULL' from the  $request->getContent() call when I run the test (of course, if I use normal browser like FF, $request->getContent() returns the JSON data correctly). So, what is your advice?

Comment: well I mean "JSON data" instead of "JSON date".

Comment: Did you try $request->getParameter('data'); or $request->getPostParameter('data'). Obviously, that you have to have data={our JSON here }. It should work.

Answer (score 0):

More of a workaround...

If you get the content in your action like this:

```
protected function getContent() {
    $content = $this->request->getParameter('content'); 
    if(!$content) $content = $this->request->getContent(); 
    return $content;
}

public function executeIndex(sfWebRequest $request) {
    $content = $this->getContent();
    //do something with your content :D
}
```

that should allow you to test what you want by passing

```
post('search', array('content' => 'whatever my content is'));
```